# Adding delay in loop execution in jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, delay

I am trying to execute few lines in the loop with 10 secs delay. adding the code below,

```
            $(xmlResponse).find("row").each(function()
            {
                setInterval(
                    //some set of code here
                ,10000);
            });
```

I dont know if i am doing it right, can any one of you please guide me ?

Regards,
Ashwin

Comment: did you run your code?

Comment: setInterval will run one time per 10 seconds, if you want to run just once, change it to setTimeout

Comment: You can't make the iterations of your loop actually wait or delay.  That isn't how javascript works.  You can schedule code to run in the future with `setTimeout()` but it isn't clear from your question if that's exactly what you want here or you really just want to slowly do your iteration, one item each 10 seconds.  Please describe in more detail what you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Kartikeya - `.delay()` only works with jQuery animations, not with `.each()`.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks for your comment.. 

i am trying to make a call to google api to get some lattitude and longitude values. As google api is lil bit slow in responding, i want my loop to iterate slow like in 5seconds or 10 seconds delay..
Please let me know if i am not clear

Comment: Are you trying to make one call to Google from your loop every 10 seconds?

Comment: @jfriend00 .. Yes ...

Comment: OK, I've provided an answer that will do that.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks .. i will check and do some test runs..

Answer (score 0):

You probably want setTimeout() as it only fires once:

```
$(xmlResponse).find("row").each(function() {
    setTimeout( //some set of code here ,10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that it's clear the OP wants to execute one operation in the `.each()` loop every 10 seconds, there are several ways to do that.  One way is to just pile up a whole bunch of `setTimeout()` calls to schedule work for the future for the whole loop.  I prefer not to do that because it makes it hard to make logic decisions about future work part way through.  Rather, I tend to change the way you iterate to a frequently used design pattern like this:

```
var rows = $(xmlResponse).find("row");
var cntr = 0;
function nextRow() {
    if (cntr < rows.length) {
        var currentRow = rows.eq(cntr);

        // do your operation on currentRow here

        ++cntr;
        // schedule the next row for 10 seconds from now
        setTimeout(nextRow, 10 * 1000);
    }
}
// start the first one
nextRow();
```